# How to run zerobrane inside Docker

Tags: docker, zerobrane

I am switching from doing most of my development on a VM inside VirtualBox to Docker.  Are there any instructions on how to set up ZBS in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the IDE itself inside a container to debug applications running inside the container. The path mapping (between the paths in the host system, where you run the IDE, and the container) should be figured out and applied automatically. The only reason you may run into an issue is when you have two or more parts of a file tree mapped to the same tree, in which case [this patch and the discussion in the ticket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/pull/849) may be of interest.

If you do want to run the IDE inside the container, there is nothing specific you need to do to get it to work.

Comment: In my application, LuaJIT serves as an interpreter and most of the performance intensive code is in C (compiled into a few .so files).  My host machine is a Mac but my development system is Ubuntu, which I am running through Docker. Consider the following file: ```local ffi = require 'ffi'
package.path = package.path .. ";/Users/z003zfg/WORK/Q//local/lib/?.so;;"
local cutils = require 'libcutils'
``` Error is: ```error loading module 'libcutils' from file '/Users/z003zfg/WORK/Q//local/lib/libcutils.so':
 /Users/z003zfg/WORK/Q//local/lib/libcutils.so:1: unexpected symbol near 'char(127)'```

Comment: This error happens because you are using `package.path` instead of `package.cpath` to configure access to binary modules.